# Django-autocomplete-light: allow free text

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-autocomplete-light

I am using `autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceWidget` from `django-autocomplete-light==1.4.13` to fill in a ManyToManyField.
It only allows selecting items from existing choices.

Is there a way to allow users to create new items on the fly with django-autocomplete-light?

If not, is there any solid alternative to it with good Django integration, which supports this feature?

Comment: I have just asked for this feature on Github: https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/290

From poking around in the code, it should be possible, but I am not sure how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/290) by @blueyed. Here is an answer from the author:

> Here's an example for v2
>     https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/autocomplete_light/example_apps/create_choice_on_the_fly
>
> That one would be for v1
>     https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/tree/master/test_project/ajax_create