# How do you allow input to be an object selection from model but also free text input in a django form?

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to have a field in a form that allows users to select objects from a Model and also allows free text input. I am using django-autocomplete-light. Although it works great for selecting choices from the model, I can't get it to allow free text input without creating new objects before the form is submitted.

Before someone marks this as duplicate, I did read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243853/django-autocomplete-light-allow-free-text) but it did not guide me into a solution.

Here's my models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

My forms.py:

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Person.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='myapp:name-autocomplete')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name',]
```

My views.py:

```
class PersonAutoComplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):

        qs = Person.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q)

        return qs
```

And my urls.py:

```
    path(
        'name-autocomplete/',
         PersonAutoComplete.as_view(create_field='name'),
         name='name-autocomplete',
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely you are missing `{{ form.media }}` in your template

Comment: That still doesn't allow me to input free text on the field.

Comment: Please see edited answer, most likely that's your issue